# Linux NIC Bonding Issue (CentOS 4 / RHEL 3)

Tags: linux, centos, ethernet, bonding

I am having an issue with bonding NICs on CentOS 4.  It appears the bonding driver does work, but it is stuck in round-robin mode and I am trying to get to active-backup.

The current config is:

ifcfg-bond0

```
DEVICE=bond0
IPADDR=192.168.204.18
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
USERCTL=no
TYPE=Bonding
BONDING_OPTS="mode=1 miimon=100"
```

ifcfg-eth1

```
DEVICE=eth1
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
```

ifcfg-eth3

```
DEVICE=eth3
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
TYPE=Ethernet
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
```

cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0

```
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v2.6.3-rh (June 8, 2005)

Bonding Mode: load balancing (round-robin)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 0
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

Slave Interface: eth1
MII Status: up
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 00:17:a4:8f:94:b1

Slave Interface: eth3
MII Status: up
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 00:1b:21:56:b8:69
```

cat /etc/modprobe.conf

```
alias eth0 tg3
alias eth1 tg3
alias eth3 e1000
alias eth2 e1000
alias bond0 bonding
options bond0 mode=1 miimon=100
```

I have tried moving the bonding information out of the ifcfg-bond0 into the modprobe configuration file.  It seems that it is stuck in RR and I am trying to get it into the Active-backup (mode 1) state.

Any ideas what would be causing this issue?

Comment: Any output from dmesg?

Comment: The only thing that stands out is:

bonding: Warning: the permanent HWaddr of eth1 - 00:17:A4:8F:94:B1 - is still in use by bond0. Set the HWaddr of eth1 to a different address to avoid conflicts. (doing ifdown, ifup bond0)

Other than that, the bond0 interface comes up, eth1 and eth3 gets enslaved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://kbase.redhat.com/faq/docs/DOC-7431

http://kbase.redhat.com/faq/docs/DOC-7944

http://kbase.redhat.com/faq/docs/DOC-2511

it seem issues with RHEL 3 and 4

Answer (score 1):

Some things to try things:

1. Check the output of dmesg
2. You still have this situation after `/etc/init.d/network restart` ?
3. `modprobe -r` the bonding module and then load it again.
4. Try arp ping with arp target instead of miimon maybe.

Comment: 1. See above comment. 

2. I have not tried the network restart as it is a production environment (I have a pre-production environment that I was able to setup bonding without restarting the networking service). 

3. I tried this as well, did not work 

4. I used mii-tool and the NICs are supported, but this may be a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

From one of several machines I have configured:

[keiths@vm-dmz-host1 ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release

CentOS release 4.8 (Final)

[keiths@vm-dmz-host1 ~]$

[keiths@myserver ~]$ uname -a

Linux myserver 2.6.9-34.ELsmp #1 SMP Wed Mar 8 00:27:03 CST 2006 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

[keiths@myserver ~]$ sudo cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0

Password:

Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v2.6.1 (October 29, 2004)

Bonding Mode: fault-tolerance (active-backup)

Primary Slave: None

Currently Active Slave: eth0

MII Status: up

MII Polling Interval (ms): 50

Up Delay (ms): 0

Down Delay (ms): 0

Slave Interface: eth0

MII Status: up

Link Failure Count: 0

Permanent HW addr: 00:0d:60:9c:35:2e

Slave Interface: eth1

MII Status: up

Link Failure Count: 0

Permanent HW addr: 00:0d:60:9c:35:2f

[keiths@myserver ~]$

[keiths@myserver ~]$ sudo cat /etc/modprobe.conf

alias scsi_hostadapter megaide

alias eth0 tg3

alias eth1 tg3

alias bond0 bonding

options bond0 mode=1 miimon=50

alias usb-controller ohci-hcd

[keiths@myserver ~]$

[keiths@myserver ~]$ sudo cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0

DEVICE=bond0

IPADDR=192.168.46.170

NETMASK=255.255.255.224

NETWORK=192.168.46.160

BROADCAST=192.168.46.191

GATEWAY=192.168.46.161

ONBOOT=yes

BOOTPROTO=none

IPV6INIT=no

USERCTL=no

[keiths@myserver ~]$

[keiths@myserver ~]$ sudo cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

DEVICE=eth0

BOOTPROTO=none

ONBOOT=yes

TYPE=Ethernet

USERCTL=no

MASTER=bond0

SLAVE=yes

HWADDR=00:0D:60:9C:35:2E

[keiths@myserver ~]$

[keiths@myserver ~]$ sudo cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1

DEVICE=eth1

BOOTPROTO=none

ONBOOT=yes

TYPE=Ethernet

USERCTL=no

MASTER=bond0

SLAVE=yes

HWADDR=00:0D:60:9C:35:2F

[keiths@myserver ~]$